# Serilog not injecting `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<T>`

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore, microsoft.extensions.logging, servicecollection

Adding Serilog to my ASP.NET Core (.NET 8) project, following the instructions in the [serilog-aspnetcore](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore) repo. Everything appears to be in order;
however if I try to inject a `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<T>` into any class in my application, it only ever recieves a `null` object. Do I need an extra step to inject those? Or am I just doing something wrong?

Main application code:

```cs
public static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
{
    var tempLogger = InitializeTemporaryLogger();

    try
    {
        var app = CreateBuilder(args, tempLogger).Build();
        ConfigureHttpPipeline(app);
        await app.RunAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "Application terminated unexpectedly");
        return 1;
    }
    finally
    {
        await Log.CloseAndFlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Temporary logger:

```cs
using MEL = Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

private static MEL.ILogger InitializeTemporaryLogger()
{
    SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));
    SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Debug(formatProvider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        .WriteTo.Console(formatProvider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        .MinimumLevel.Information()
        // Can't use this for now, due to bug during parallel xUnit integration tests
        // https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/issues/289
        //.CreateBootstrapLogger();
        .CreateLogger();

    // Wrap the temporary Serilog logger in a Microsoft.Extensions.Logging wrapper
    using var factory = new SerilogLoggerFactory(Log.Logger);
    return factory.CreateLogger<Program>();
    }
```

Application builder code:

```cs
using MEL = Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

private static WebApplicationBuilder CreateBuilder(string[] args, MEL.ILogger? logger = null)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // ...

    builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, provider, config) =>
    {
        config
            // These features are required, and thus hard-coded
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Debug(formatProvider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            .WriteTo.Console(formatProvider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            // All other settings come from config
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration);
    });

    // ...

    return builder;
}
```

When running the application, the bootstrapping code writes to Serilog (console) successfully. So does the HTTP request middleware. So I know at least that much is wired up correctly.

Looking in the DI registrations, I can see a couple initial entries by Microsoft; then towards the end I see the Serilog entries. But nothing from Serilog about `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<T>`:

| DI Index | Service Type | Implementation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory` | `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory` |
| 15 | `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger'1` | `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger'1` |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 210 | `Serilog.SerilogServiceCollectionExtensions+RegisteredLogger` | *<factory>* |
| 211 | `Serilog.ILogger` | *<factory>* |
| 212 | `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory` | *<factory>* |
| 213 | `Serilog.Extensions.Hosting.DiagnosticContext` | *<factory>* |
| 214 | `Serilog.IDiagnosticContext` | *<factory>* |

When I retrieve an `ILoggerFactory` from DI, I do get the `SerilogLoggerFactory` back as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The `Repository` class, used for testing was wired up in DI using a factory method, and that factory method was passing a hard-coded `null` logger into the constructor.

Tip: Check your own class' DI config.